# Oxidative deamination with chemfig

Tags: equations, chemfig

I want to make an equation with chemfig but i've a problem with arrow and the name of the enzyme.

I would like a reaction like this :

[image: Desamination oxydative]

I'm a novice with the latex code. For the moment I managed to make this code :

```
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{H_2N-[,0.5]C(-[2,0.5]H)(-[6,0.5]R)-[,0.5]COOH}}{Acide aminé}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{H_2O}}{Eau}
\arrow{-U>[$NAD^{+}$][$NADH,H^{+}$][8pt][0.5][90]}
\chemname{\chemfig{R-[,0.5]C^\alpha(-[,0.5]COOH)=[2,0.5]O}}{Acide $\alpha$-cétonique}
\
\
\    
\
\
\+
\
\
\
\
\
\chemname{\chemfig{NH_3}}{Ammoniaque}
\schemestop
```

But with the U arrow I'm limited. I can't succeed and I haven't notions to make this equation.

Sorry for my bad English :'(

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `chemfig` is based on Ti*k*Z so you may be better off if you draw this just with Ti*k*Z. Would you be willing to consider a mainly Ti*k*Z solution as well?

Comment: Hi, thanks ! Yes, why not ! I will learn about this package ! :) 
I have a lot of biochemistry classes and I must control Latex code if I want to make beautiful presentations.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is wrong. There are errors ! First, I'm going to try to understand Tikz and make my own custom arrow and then I will apply that with chemfig.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own arrow based on already defined arrows. For example like this:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}

\makeatletter
\definearrow7{-uU>}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#5}%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)node[midway](Uarrow@arctangent){};%
    \CF@ifempty{#6}
        {\def\CF@Uarrow@radius{0.333}}
        {\def\CF@Uarrow@radius{#6}}%
    \CF@ifempty{#7}%
        {\def\CF@Uarrow@absangle{60}}
        {\pgfmathsetmacro\CF@Uarrow@absangle{abs(#7)}}% ne prendre en compte que la valeur absolue de l'angle
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#1}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Uarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@Uarrow@radius,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,delta angle=-\CF@Uarrow@absangle]node(Uarrow@start){};
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#2}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}}]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Uarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@Uarrow@radius,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle-90,delta angle=\CF@Uarrow@absangle]node(Uarrow@end){};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF@tmp@str{\CF@Uarrow@radius*cos(\CF@arrow@current@angle)<0?"-":"+"}%
    \ifdim\CF@Uarrow@radius pt>\z@
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0}\CF@tmp@str{Uarrow@start}{#2}{1}\CF@tmp@str{Uarrow@end}%
    \else
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#2}{0}\CF@tmp@str{Uarrow@start}{#1}{1}\CF@tmp@str{Uarrow@end}%
    \fi
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#3}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Uarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@Uarrow@radius,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,delta angle=\CF@Uarrow@absangle]node(Uarrow@start){};
    \edef\CF@tmp@str{[\CF@ifempty{#4}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF@arrow@current@style}}]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF@tmp@str (Uarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[radius=\CF@compound@sep*\CF@current@arrow@length*\CF@Uarrow@radius,start angle=\CF@arrow@current@angle+90,delta angle=-\CF@Uarrow@absangle]node(Uarrow@end){};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF@tmp@str{\CF@Uarrow@radius*cos(\CF@arrow@current@angle)<0?"+":"-"}%
    \ifdim\CF@Uarrow@radius pt>\z@
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#3}{0}\CF@tmp@str{Uarrow@start}{#4}{1}\CF@tmp@str{Uarrow@end}%
    \else
        \CF@arrow@display@label{#4}{0}\CF@tmp@str{Uarrow@start}{#3}{1}\CF@tmp@str{Uarrow@end}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
\chemname[20pt]{\chemfig{H_2N-[,0.5]C(-[2,0.5]H)(-[6,0.5]R)-[,0.5]COOH}}{Acide aminé}
\arrow{-uU>[\ce{NAD^{+}}][\ce{NADH,H^{+}}][\ce{H_2O}][\ce{NH_3}][15pt][.5][80]}
\chemname[20pt]{\chemfig{R-[,0.5]C^\alpha(-[,0.5]COOH)=[2,0.5]O}}{Acide $\alpha$-cétonique}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Which yields (may need some fine-tuning though):

[image]